# Using multiple if then statements in where clause in SQL

Tags: sql, if-statement, boolean, where-clause

I am trying to insert multiple if then statements into a where clause in SQL.

For instance, if location = 1, then use date range keydate >= '09/30/13 23:00:00.000' and keydate < '10/31/13 23:00:00.000', if location = 2 then another date range.

The reason I want to do this is because I have many queries for different timezones and I would like to consolidate all these into one. Below is a simplified example of the query.

I have read about using case statements and boolean logic as approaches to solving similar problems, but cant figure out if this will work for multiple criteria(ie multiple office ID)

Also writing the syntax is challenging due to my inexperience.

```
select sum(r.revenue) as revenue
from customer_stats
where cus.office_id = '1' --would like to insert "if" cus.office_id = 1 then use keydate 
and keydate >= '09/30/13 23:00:00.000' and keydate < '10/31/13 23:00:00.000'
```

Answer (score 0):

It's all in how you nest your where clause.

```
select sum(r.revenue) as revenue
from customer_stats
where 
    (
        cus.office_id = '1'
        and keydate >= '09/30/13 23:00:00.000' 
        and keydate < '10/31/13 23:00:00.000' 
    )
    OR 
    (
        cus.office_id = '2'
        and keydate >= '08/30/13 23:00:00.000' 
        and keydate < '09/31/13 23:00:00.000' 
    )
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! I will try this out now. One question before I test many offices is: will this exponentially increase the execution time or just linearly increase it?

Comment: It won't be exponential.  Just make sure that office_id and keydate are indexed and the query should be pretty quick.

Comment: hm I tried this approach for two small offices and stopped the query after 30 min. I greatly narrowed the criteria and using OR's did work, but if I used all office ID's I think the query would take days to complete, which will not work.

Comment: Do you have indexes on keydate and office_id?

Comment: sorry but I am not too familiar with index, after 30 min of researching I have learned not too much. Any tips??

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 'Decode' function. Here is the syntax

```
DEOCDE(expr,s1,r1,s2,r2,....., default)
```

So, if expression 'expr' equals to s1, it will return r1; for s2, r2; if nothing matches it will consider a default value.. Heres an example snippet you can use in your query...

```
   DECODE(X,'A',50,'B',10,50)
```

So above snippet will return 50 if X='A'; 10 if X='B' Orelse by default 50. 
Hope this will help :)